# Visual studio Code - devcontainer extensions not installing behind VPN

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I have a devcontainer.json set up with the following property:

```
"extensions": ["esbenp.prettier-vscode"],
```

Unfortunately, while I'm on VPN; the extension doesn't install (I can install it locally/manually).

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the HTTP_PROXY explicitly in my .devcontainer file was the fix for me being behind a corporate firewall. Make sure you rebuild the container.

```
"containerEnv": {
    "HTTP_PROXY": "{your proxy}"
},
```